# Alinhar texto horizontalmente em relação a imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alinhar o texto de alguns produtos em relação a imagem, mas não estou obtendo sucesso no que estou fazendo, o que tenho é isso:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
     <a href="detalhes.php?prod=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_produto']; ?>" title=""> <img src="<?php echo $imagemThumb; ?>" alt="" /></a>
     <p align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProdutos['nome']; ?></p>
    </div>
```

Tentei alterar a referência no meu `css` nas opções onde se encontram valores para `left` mas as alterações não surtiram efeito algum, o css relacionado é esse:

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/*  06 - Estilos Portfolio
/*------------------------------------------*/

.portfolio-filter {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-filter li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.portfolio-filter li a {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-filter li a:hover {
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.portfolio-filter li a.selected, .portfolio-filter li a.selected:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-4 {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.portfolio-4 .portfolio-item {
    width: 24.99%!important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-border {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-border {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay i {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -27px;
    margin-top: -19px;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay i {
    top: 50%;
    color: #444;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details {
    position: relative;
    padding: 9px 12px 6px 12px;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link i, .portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link span {
    color: #aaa;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link:hover i, .portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link:hover span {
    color: #F54B5C;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details h4 {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details a span {
    color: #000;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details span:after {
    content: ", ";
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-details span:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Imagem de como estou tentando deixar 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Página: [Produtos](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/produtos.php)

Comment: poste uma imagem ilustrativa de como deveria ficar o texto em relação a imagem.

Comment: já tentou dar um text-align: center na div "portfolio-item" ?

Comment: Você está usando align na tag <p>. Use sempre o text-align via css :)

Comment: Olá @DiChrist, fiz isso na tag p.

Comment: adventista, use isso na div, irá centralizar tudo o que estiver na div

Comment: Acabei de fazer e as imagens ficaram bagunçadas @DiChrist.

Comment: Tem muitos elementos estilizados no css que não aparecem no html. Poste uma imagem ou coloque um link para a página para que possamos ver. Pode ser que algum desses elementos possam estar atrapalhando a resolver o problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É porque a imagem é menor que o bloco faça isto:

```
.portfolio-item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

E tanto as imagens quanto o texto vão centralizar, note que é desnecessário o uso de `align="center"` no `<p>` prefira usar CSS.

Comment: Olá @Guilherme Nascimento, obrigado pela excelente dica, tinha feito esse teste anteriormente mas não sei porque razão não funcionou, acha que apavorei, muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: foi o que pedi para fazer lá nos comentários, o autor tinha dito que não tinha dado certo, então imaginei que pudesse ser outro elemento atrapalhando.

Comment: @adventistapr é que você talvez tenha aplicado no elemento `<p>` apenas ou tenha colocado algum elemento em `block`, imagens em block não alinham, por padrão `<img>` é `inline` ;)

Comment: @DiChrist não vi seu comentário, agora o notei, vou dar up pra ele, eu acho que o autor se confundiu mesmo, por isso que as vezes já formular uma resposta com um código pronto ajuda a errar menos hehehehe :) não tenha medo de responder.

Comment: ih que nada mano :) O importante mesmo é ele ter chegado a resolução do problema! Up na resposta :)

Comment: Olá @DiChrist, foi exatamente isso que fiz, me confundi, obrigado pela dica.